# How to solve constrained matrix equation?

Tags: matrices, vectors

I am trying to solve for the $1 \times n$ vector $X$ such that
$$X T = X$$

where $\operatorname{sum}(X) = 1$ and $T$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. The $\operatorname{sum}(X)$ condition is that all elements of the vector $X$ must sum to $1$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT::

T is a known matrix!

Comment: What is the context? Have you learned solving system of linear equations? Gaussian elimination?

Comment: @road_to_quantdom Is $T$ known or do you want a general formula?

Comment: T is known, so a general formula is not necessary!